# How to retrieve keychain from iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

I store password to the keychain when the user logs in. Now I'm working on change password page. I want to compare the keychain password with old password. How do I retrieve the keychain password?

I'm using **ASIHttpRequest** to validate user. **ASIHttpRequest** stores the password in the keychain.

```
[request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
[request setShouldPresentAuthenticationDialog:TRUE];
[request setShouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge:TRUE];
```

Can someone help me how do I get the stored password from Keychain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following simple blog post about [keychain](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html) help me to store and retrieve keychain values from iphone app. As Rob Napier posted answer to ASIHttpRequest framework but I found it bit complicated and I started using Apple KeychainItemWrapper class and it's very easy to implement. I will mark this as answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `ASIHTTPRequest`, you can use its keychain interface in `ASIHTTPRequest.h`:

```
// Return credentials from the keychain
+ (NSURLCredential *)savedCredentialsForHost:(NSString *)host port:(int)port protocol:(NSString *)protocol realm:(NSString *)realm;
```

There are several other routines that should be of interest in that file. Search for "keychain".

Comment: I'm lost with this method. If you could give me bit more specific answer I will appreciate.